# Reset all elements inside class

Tags: javascript, reset

Is there a way to reset all the elements to its default value?

I tried this one but nothing's happen

```
<script>
c = document.getElementsByClassName('myall')

for( b=0; b<c.length; b++ )
{
    c[b].reset();
}
<script>
```

.

```
<div class='myall'>
    <span>something default</span>
    <div>something default</div>
    <p>something default</p>
</div>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: What is your concept of ["default value"](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/html.html#ID-26091157)? That only has meaning for form controls.

Comment: you can't reset elements like `<span>` or `<div>`, only `<form>` can be reseted and not partially

Comment: @RobG what I mean is, the default text or value inside that element. In my example, I have 'something default'

Answer (score 0):

The javascript method `.reset()` applies only to the `<form>` tag. If you want an easy way of clearing input values or element text with a specific class, you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/empty/).

Otherwise, use something like this for elements like `div`, `span`:

```
c[b].innerHTML = "";
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your code for closing  tag.Then use,

```
<script>
  var c = document.getElementsByClassName('myall')
 for( var b=0; b<c.length; b++ )
 {
     c[b].html(default_value);
 }
</script>
```

**html**

```
<div class='myall'>
   <span id="a">something default</span>
   <div id="b">something default</div>
   <p id="c">something default</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To "reset" and element, you'll need to remember its original content, then replace it later when called to "reset" it, e.g.

```
var markupCache = {};

function modifyElement(id, newMarkup) {

    var el = document.getElementById(id);

    // Only store innerHTML the first time
    if (!(el in markupCache)) {
      markupCache[id] = document.getElementById(id).innerHTML;
    }
    el.innerHTML = markup;
}

function restoreElement(id) {

  // Only restore markup if have cached some for this element
  if (id in markupCache) {
    document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = markupCache[id];
  }
}
```

Note that this will not reset the element's own properties and attributes, only the internal HTML. That may be fixed in part by using the [*outerHTML*](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/apis-in-html-documents.html#outerhtml) property, but that isn't well supported.

Both *innerHTML* or *outerHTML* will not restore dynamically added listeners and may or may not restore original default values in some browsers (but it will in others).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with HTML5 data-* attributes:

```
<div id='myall'>
    <span data-default="something default">something default</span>
    <div data-default="something default">something default</div>
    <p data-default="something default">something default</p>
</div>     ​
...
<script>
    c = document.getElementById('myall').children;

    for( b=0; b < c.length; b++ )
    { 
        defaultValue = c[b].getAttribute('data-default');
        if (defaultValue) {
            c[b].innerText = defaultValue;
        }
    }
</script>
```

​